# Parsing a one column JSON file in iOS into an array?

Tags: ios, xcode, json

I have managed to get a list of locations from my webserver using JSON and have the file grabbed from the app.
I know it can get the etc as I have printed it too the NSLog and it appears in JSON in the log window.

My next step is getting these values into an array so I can eventually display them into a UIPickerView.

Anybody any suggestions on how I can best get them into an array from the current JSON file?

Key is 'name'.

I can't for the life of me get it to loop through and add to array; maybe I am doing it wrong?

JSON data looks like:

```
[{"Name":"Aberdaron"},{"Name":"Aberdeen"},{"Name":"Aberdovey"},{"Name":"Aberporth"},{"Name":"Aberystwyth"},{"Name":"Albert-Bridge"},{"Name":"Aldeburgh"},{"Name":"Allington-Lock"},{"Name":"Alloa"},{"Name":"Amble"},{"Name":"Amlwch"},{"Name":"Annan-Waterfoot"},{"Name":"Anstruther-Easter"},{"Name":"Applecross"},{"Name":"Appledore"},{"Name":"Arbroath"},{"Name":"Ardglass"},{"Name":"Ardnave-Point"},{"Name":"Ardrossan"},{"Name":"Arklow"},{"Name":"Arnside"},{"Name":"Arrochar"}]
```

Code that I have so far is:

```
    NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/Locations.php"];
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError * error;
NSMutableArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",json);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first answer has given a good description of how to parse the array and put it into a native object.  I have written a function which is a category on NSString that you can use below.  Assuming that your array is stored in a variable called json, I would use the following code, given your example:

```
NSMutableArray *nameArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in json)
{
    [nameArray addObject:[dictionary valueForKey:@"Name"]];
}
NSLog(@"%@",nameArray);
```

Now nameArray is an array of all the values corresponding to the "name" keys given in your example.

Comment: Hi, Looks like that will work but throws me an error "No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'addObject:'"

Comment: I had a typo, I declared it as an NSArray, instead should be mutable :)

Comment: [Why re-invent the wheel?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel) NSArray has [valueForKey](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/valueForKey:) which does the same thing as above answer. You dont need a new category for something which is already there. `NSArray *nameArray = [json valueForKey:@"Name"];` is same as above.

Comment: Yes, as stated in my answer below, an hour before this answer was posted.

Answer (score 0):

So your JSON already is coming down as an array (denoted by the fact that your key/value pairs are enclosed in hard brackets `[ ]`). Assuming you're not using any 3rd party JSON consumption libraries, you can use iOS's built in `NSJSONSerialization` to turn the JSON data into an Objective-C object. You're probably going to want the class method `+ (id)JSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)data options:(NSJSONReadingOptions)opt error:(NSError **)error`, which simply takes a pointer to some NSData, an options flag, and a pointer to an NSError.

Notice the method returns type `id`, but since your JSON is coming down in an array, go ahead and stick it in an array variable. Now, you have an array of `NSDictionary`s that you can loop through. Assuming your array is named `jsonDataArray`, the code to plop all the names in an array for your picker is very simple. You could, of course, create an `NSMutableArray` and loop through your initial array, adding the result of `objectForKey:` from your dictionary to the mutable array.

A much simpler and elegant approach would be a simple one-liner:

```
NSArray *names = [jsonDataArray valueForKey:@"Name"];
```

When used on an array, valueForKey will grab all values of an object for that key. Since your objects are `NSDictionary`s, the values will be what you need!

Comment: Thanks. It appears that that would work OK but for some reason there is no key value, so its throwing an error.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this please?

Comment: +1. Not sure why this was downvoted. This should work perfectly.

Comment: @LyconalBest, could you explain how there is no key value? There is very clearly a key in a dictionary -- that's kind of how they work

Comment: @jmstone, xcode was error messaging me that there was no key value available.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with the way you are creating your array. This code works: NSArray *array = @[@{@"Name":@"Aberdaron"},@{@"Name":@"Aberdeen"},@{@"Name":@"Aberdovey"},@{@"Name":@"Aberporth"}];
    
NSLog(@"%@", [array valueForKey:@"Name"]);